# Customizar jekyll para publicaciones

Tags: html, web, jekyll

Estoy tratando de customizar los layouts de jekyll, sin embargo estoy utilizando jekyll admin para crear mis publicaciones dentro de mi sitio y no sé como personalizar los layout que uno puede selececionar dentro de estos

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Jekyll admin permite dentro de su panel seleccionar un layout para tu publicación pero no sé como modificar su diseño para mis necesidades